# Integrated CMOS battery, how can I reset BIOS?

Tags: bios, motherboard, battery, lenovo-laptop, cmos

So to explain, I have a Lenovo Thinkpad x13 Yoga Gen 1 with integrated CMOS battery.

My problem is, I don't have the BIOS password.

Recently Lenovo released an update (Firmware update on windows) after the update pc reboots its self to install the recent update, unfortunately after the reboot, system asks for BIOS password.

> "System Security: Supervisor Password Required" .

I don't have the password for bios and I have been using the laptop for 2 years and I have never needed it before.

For normal laptops we could just remove CMOS battery and reset bios, but in this case there is no battery because of integrated battery on motherboard.

Besides buying a new motherboard (which is really expensive), how can I reset my BIOS?

Is there a way to by-pass the system or somehow remove integrated CMOS battery?

Comment: Is there not a jumper near the CMOS battery, where you can short 2 pins or remove a little 2-pin header?

Comment: Pretty sure CMOS batteries on consumer hardware are removable - I did a quick google and saw a slightly different Thinkpad model with one of those CR2032 batteries wrapped in yellow plastic, with a wire soldered on... Still used a 2 pin header to connect to the main board, so easily removable. Shakesbeer: I would check if this is the case.

Comment: Hey guys, I haven't opened the laptop yet. I'll check your comments. Thank you very for your comments.

Comment: Have you contacted Lenovo Support?  I use Lenovo machines all the time and updating BIOS does not set a BIOS password.

Comment: It doesn't sets a BIOS pw. If there is a bios pw, it asks you after the update. and u cannot skip it